# Python's logging module not working with ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, python, logging

I have a Python script imported to an Arc toolbox. It uses Python's logging module for message recording.

```
import logging
import time
import os, sys
import arcpy

logging.basicConfig(filename='log.log', format='%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s: %(message)s', datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

When run as a standart Python file it created the log file successfully. However, when I ran it from the Toolbox in ArcMap, the log file was not created. It seems logging is not working with ArcPy. Any idea?